# Logistic regression with interaction in R, what to test for final conclusion?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interaction

I think I have a pretty basic question, but I am not sure what the right thing to do is.

Performing logistic regression confirms the obvious interaction seen in the raw data (see below). How should I follow up on this for a final report? Can you look at the data and decide to only do one test for gt on div14, and one test for gt on div35 because that is where the obvious change is? Or is "blindly" testing gt for each level of div the proper thing to do? Why not test for div, on each level of gt? Experimentally, that is also interesting but it would come down to pretty much the same conclusion...

Raw data available at http://pastebin.com/XeqXLxSP
R code:

```
library(ggplot2)

tblr <- read.table("tblr.txt")
tblr$gt = factor(tblr$gt, levels=c("wt","ako","bko"))
tblr$div = factor(tblr$div, levels=c("7","14","35","63"))

mdl = glm(t3 ~ gt*div, family=binomial(link='logit'), data=tblr)
anova(mdl, test="Chisq")

ggplot(tblr, aes(x=div, y=t3, group=gt, colour=gt)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.6)) +
  stat_summary(position = position_dodge(0.6)) +
  stat_summary(position = position_dodge(0.6), geom = "line")
```

Output:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table
Model: binomial, link: logit
Response: t3
Terms added sequentially (first to last)

       Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev  Pr(>Chi)    
NULL                     191     215.94              
gt      2   7.3195       189     208.62 0.0257389 *  
div     3  15.2498       186     193.37 0.0016152 ** 
gt:div  6  23.0998       180     170.27 0.0007637 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[image: logistic regression interaction]

Answer (score 1):

If div is a continuous variable measured to the nearest multiple of seven it does seem a rather strange pattern. Why does one dip at one value of div, another at a different value of div, and the third not at all? Rather than carrying out further statistical analysis and significance testing I would ask the scientists who gave you the data what they think is happening here.

Comment: I am the scientist myself ;) So gt stands for genotype and wt (wildtype) are control with ako and bko being different transgenic mice. Their cells are tested on different days in vitro (div). It is of interest that they dip on different timepoints.

Answer (score 0):

Since both variables have four levels, a complete analysis, in my opinion, would be to provide all odds ratios of combinations of the levels the variables. You would need a little math and the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients if you would like to present the 95% CI to distinguish which combination may or may not have statistically significance interaction. Of course, it will be okay to ignore any combination which does not make sense in the domain of the problem. This will only enrich your discussion of the model and its usefulness

Comment: But then that adds a lot of extra tests, which would need to be corrected for multiple comparisons..? As opposed to doing a select few tests to confirm what you think you see in the data.

Comment: No, this is not a multiple comparison problem. You are simply reporting the odds ratio based on your model. Unfortunately, odds ratio and their confidence intervals cannot be readily reported for variables with interaction since a little algebra is needed. To say it is multiple comparison may be likened to saying that each odd ratio and CI you report from your model constitutes a separate test instead of the simple null hypotheses that all your regression coefficients are zero